# How to setup a CakePHP project for Jenkins on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, cakephp, jenkins

I haven't been able to find an easy way to config Jenkins with a Cakephp project on my localhost to implement Continuos Integration properly.

Would be appreciated if someone supply an easy to understand tutorial, from configuring Jenkins to run Cakephp test units.

Thanks

Comment: Setting up all the dependencies on Windows isn't easy. You might be better off using a headless virtual machine ([Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)) and the [Jenkins PHP template](http://jenkins-php.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As said by @xgalvin getting all the dependencies running on Windows is a messy and error prone task. You'd be better of with what he suggested or an Linux based server - be it a virtual machine or not. Anyway definitely use the [Jenkins PHP template](http://jenkins-php.org/). I've personally done this a couple of times and the first time it was a bit of a hassle but it is not very hard to do. All you need is basic knowledge of Linux/bash/PHP/Jenkins and some time.